# Catel validation on PasswordBox is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

Not working validation for `PasswordBox`.
Not highlighted in red border and no message when I hover on a `PasswordBox`. 
For `TextBox` it works well.
How resolve this problem?

```or-tag-here
<TextBox Height="23" Margin="10,40,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         Text="{Binding Login, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"   Width="220"/>
<PasswordBox  Margin="10,100,10,0" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="220" >
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <catel:UpdateBindingOnPasswordChanged Password="{Binding Password,  Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</PasswordBox>
```

C# code

```or-tag-here
  protected override void ValidateFields(List<IFieldValidationResult> validationResults)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Login))
        {
            validationResults.Add(FieldValidationResult.CreateError(LoginProperty, "Login cannot be empty"));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
        {
            validationResults.Add(FieldValidationResult.CreateError(PasswordProperty, "Password cannot be empty"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the PasswordBox is not bindable. This means it cannot detect any validation results because of that binding (because it cannot bind).

I am not sure if it's possible to propagate the error from the UpdateBindingOnPasswordChanged behavior to the PasswordBox.

Comment: Maybe, do you know another way to resolve this problem?